# Mostrar echo dentro de una variable en php

Tags: php

Hola estoy haciendo una pagina web en php pero estoy utilizando un template que lo incluyo al php y la pagina la modifico en php solo que a veces necesito recurrir al html, para ello muestro el contenido desde el template. No se si sea el mejor modo de hacer una pagina web no tengo mucha experiencia en PHP. Bueno lo que estoy intentando es que el echo se muestre dentro de content pero no consegui ninguna novedad. Codigo:

codigo Php donde diseño la pagina diferente al template:

```
<?php

require_once 'database.php';
$database_connection = database_connect();

$title='hola';

$content='<div>';

//user input
$page = isset($_GET['page']) ? (int)$_GET['page'] : 1;
*** Lo muestra fuera del template ****
echo $perPage = isset($_GET['per-page']) && $_GET['per-page'] <= 50 ? (int)$_GET['per-page'] : 5;

$content .= '</div>';


include 'Template.php';
?>
```

Codigo php del template:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title><?php echo $title; ?></title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Styles/Stylesheet.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="wrapper">
            <div id="banner">             
            </div>

            <nav id="navigation">
                <ul id="nav">
                    <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="tool.php">Coffee</a></li>
                    <li><a href="manager.php">Shop</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>

            <div id="content_area">
                <?php echo $content; ?>
            </div>

            <div id="sidebar">

            </div>

            <footer>
                <p>All rights reserved</p>
            </footer>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Cualquier sugerencias son bien recibidas. gracias por su ayuda.

Answer (score 1):

Verás no deverías hacer un echo, ya que són páginas diferentes y no reconoce la variable, deberías poner en este caso, en la página dónde tienes el html poner un `include("ruta-al-fichero-que-quieres-añadir");` o el `require_once("lo-mismo")`

[Include()](http://php.net/manual/es/function.include.php)

[Require_once()](http://php.net/manual/es/function.require-once.php)

Te recomiendo que te leas las funciones para tener más conocimiento de causa :)

Luego ya te reconocerá las variables del otro fichero.

Comment: que es mejor hacer el php por separado o junto al html, e incluir dentro del html el php que estoy programando. Aunque es cierto que al final recurro a html gracias por su solucion

Comment: Mejor php separado, te entenderás mejor.

Comment: Aparte tu variable `$content` esta mal, al inicio tambien deberia concatenarse `$content .= "<div>"` sino le estas diciendo que $content solo tenga `<div>` y al final le estas cambiando el valor por el cierre del div `</div>`

Answer (score 1):

te recomiendo utilizar una funcion que reemplace el contenido del html y despues de tener procesado el archivo HTML lo imprimas con el **echo** $html;

Se utilizan dos funciones, la primera carga la plantilla html:

```
function carga_plantilla($nombre=''){
    $ruta='./'.$nombre.'.html';
    return file_get_contents($ruta);
}
```

La segunda funcion reemplaza el contenido del **HTML** por variables:

```
function reemplazo_dinamico($html='', $valor='', $static=''){
    $html = str_replace('{'.$static.'}', $valor, $html);
    return $html;
}
```

**Tu archivo PHP quedaría así:**

```
    <?php

        /* CARGA EL HTML */
        function carga_plantilla($nombre=''){
            $ruta='./'.$nombre.'.html';
            return file_get_contents($ruta);
        }
        /* REEMPLAZA LO QUE SE ENCUENTRA ENTRE CORCHETES */
        function reemplazo_dinamico($html='', $valor='', $static=''){
            $html = str_replace('{'.$static.'}', $valor, $html);
            return $html;
        }

        $title='hola';

        $content='<div>PRUEBAS</div>';

        /* FUNCION QUE CARGA LA PLANTILLA TEMPLATE */
        $html = carga_plantilla('template');
        /* FUNCION QUE REEMPLAZA {title} por el contenido de la variable $title*/
        $html = reemplazo_dinamico($html,$title,'title');
        /* FUNCION QUE REEMPLAZA {content} por el contenido de la variable $content*/
        $html = reemplazo_dinamico($html,$content,'content');
        echo $html;
        ?>
```

**Y tu archivo HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
            <title>{title}</title>
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Styles/Stylesheet.css" />
        </head>
        <body>
            <div id="wrapper">
                <div id="banner">             
                </div>

                <nav id="navigation">
                    <ul id="nav">
                        <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="tool.php">Coffee</a></li>
                        <li><a href="manager.php">Shop</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>

                <div id="content_area">
                    {content}
                </div>

                <div id="sidebar">

                </div>

                <footer>
                    <p>All rights reserved</p>
                </footer>
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>
```

En la plantilla HTML puedes agregar **{nombres_claves}** que despues reemplazas por $variables_claves, en este caso {title} {content}.
Éste método es base actual de muchos framework

Comment: hola este metodo resulta mas util espero su contestacion gracias

Comment: la primera duda que tengo que hace exactamente un framework ya que no tengo mucha idea ni nunca trabaje con ellos, son utiles?

Comment: framework se refiere a esto de wordpress, drupal, joomla??

Comment: Es un ambiente de trabajo para desarrollo de software, en la estructura y un conjunto de métodos que te llevan a cabo distintas tareas.

Son utiles? depende mucho de tu proyecto, lo ideal es que si utilizas un framework hagas uso completo de todas las capacidades del framework, entonces para proyectos pequeños mejor no utilizarlos.

Answer (score 0):

el problema es que estas haciendo un echo, debes llenar la variable $content con los datos que quieres mostrar dentro del template, ya que estas imprimiendo la variable cotent en el template.

```
echo $perPage = isset($_GET['per-page']) && $_GET['per-page'] <= 50 ? (int)$_GET['per-page'] : 5;
```

Deberías más bien llenar la variable, haciendo algo como:

```
$content= isset($_GET['per-page']) && $_GET['per-page'] <= 50 ? (int)$_GET['per-page'] : 5;
```

Saludos, espero te ayude.